# Inserting records into MySQL with node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

Fetching records from a form with ajax to insert into mysql with node.js but only the first column works. The rest of the columns do not insert. Below is my code. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

**Ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
$("#new-user-form").on('submit',(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var data = {};
data.title  = $('#title').val();
data.fname  = $('#fname').val();
data.mname  = $('#mname').val();
data.lname  = $('#lname').val();
data.mdname = $('#mdname').val();
$('#loading').show();
//toastr.success('Page Loaded!');
$.ajax({
url: "/new-user",
type: "POST",            
data: data,
dataType: 'application/json',
cache: false,        
success: function(data) 
{
 console.log('working');
 $('#loading').hide();
}
});
}));
});
```

**new-user.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
router  = express.Router(),
db      = require('./../db');

router.post('/', function (req,res,next) {
  var title       = req.body.title;
  var first_name  = req.body.fname;
  var middle_name = req.body.mname;
  var last_name   = req.body.lname;
  var maiden_name = req.body.mdname;
  db.insert({first_name:first_name},{last_name:last_name}).into('users').then(function(data){
    //res.send(data);
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql?

Try pass the object as one:

```
db.insert({first_name:first_name, last_name:last_name})
```

Insted of

```
db.insert({first_name:first_name},{last_name:last_name})
```

Comment: I did that but still inserts only the first column. Thanks

Comment: And what model do you use for mysql connection?

Comment: Am using knex with mysql

Comment: Every argument in "insert" function is new row but I believe you found that in the documentation by yourself. Can you show us your table structure? Do you see some errors?

Comment: I forgot to take off one of the curly braces as suggested. Thanks